# CSS working only with !important

Tags: css

I am facing the strangest issue.

I am just starting out on a new website, and I have something like:

```
html {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Well, my text turns out to be in Serif.
If I check in inspect element, it shows as crossed out.
If I search in the stylesheet, i find only this spot with a font-family declaration.

If I add *!important* then Arial works.

Anybody knows what's going on? Thanks

Comment: Do you see any other styles within the inspect tool overriding your styles? Some browsers can have default styles I believe, but it's odd that this would only override them with the `!important` flag.

Comment: check your references, you must have styling elsewhere, inline, header, or external, that is overriding your style.

Comment: google chrome developer mode will show you where an elements gets its styling from

Comment: Do you have just the one style sheet?

Comment: Here is a screenshot from inspect element http://monosnap.com/image/spct2hXP70xmd0C6Uybpd6bPrCIDCW

Comment: I found it. It's the "font: inherit". I have no clue why it happens, but it does. I am using Eric Meyer's CSS reset by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general `font-family` should be set on the `<body>` tag, not `<html>`. It's likely that you have the `serif` font set on the body which overwrites the rule.

In reply to the comments, you set the `font-family` above the global reset, which is wrong. There is `html {font: inherit;}` in the reset which overwrites the rule you set above, and the browser default font is `serif` in most of the case. That's why it renders `serif` instead of `arial`.

Comment: No I actually don't. but you can have a look here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15465969/example/index.html

Comment: If I assign the font on the body, the inherit makes it go away too.

Comment: @Akmur you should have move you custom css down below the global reset, again set the font family on the body tag is a better way to do.

Comment: That's right! Sorry for wasting your time, I didn't notice

Comment: @Akmur no worries, I think you just didn't notice that, and sometimes it's frustrating couldn't figure out what was wrong.